# Incorrect RSA1 identifier when pinging using ansible

Tags: ssh, rsa, ansible

`ssh ubuntu@ip-of-server -i ~/.ssh/foo.pem` works

but `ansible -i setup-hosts web-servers -m ping -vvvv` => Incorrect RSA1 identifier (even after i run ssh-add ~/.ssh/foo.pem)

any ideas?

Comment: it's hard to know what servers are involved here. please share the hosts file and the output from `ansible` (since you are running it via `-vvvv` already).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu in the hosts file.